# CORS is not functioning successfully in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, cors

I'm using ASP.NET CORE 6 to write an WEB API, and I want my user interface in different domain can make a request to the API.
(I use Windows Form .Net to write the UI)

So I refer to ([this site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0)) and add some code to enable CORS in the program.cs

But after some tests, I found that CORS still can't function successfully.

This is my program.cs:

```
var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                      policy =>
                      {
//192.168.100.60 is another computer's IP                          
policy.WithOrigins("https://192.168.100.60:7214/api/Email")     
                                              .AllowAnyOrigin()
                                              .AllowAnyHeader()
                                              .AllowAnyMethod();

                      });
});

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
   
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

### When I use Postman and UI to test the enabling of CORS in the same computer, it can work successfully.

[Test in Postman__the same computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DC7TK.png)

[Test in my UI__the same computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ozh1S.png)
("Email sent successfully" means the connection is successful)

### But when I use the same UI in another computer, it can't work.

[test in my UI__another computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypzUS.png)

[test in browser__another computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NursR.png)

I have refer to the code on so many webs in order to edit my program.cs code of adding CORS function but still can't work. Can anyone help me ><

By the way, the function I'm writing for is to let user input an email address in UI, and the UI will send the request to API to POST the Email address.

### This is the code of my API:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace PracticeAPI2
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class EmailController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SendEmail([FromBody] EmailRequest request)  
        {
            // You can add email processing logic here
            // For this example, we'll just return a success response
            await Task.Delay(100); // Simulate some asynchronous processing
            string email = request.Email;
            return Ok(new { Success = true, Message = "Email received and processed successfully." }); 

        }

    }
}
```

```
namespace PracticeAPI2
{
    public class EmailRequest
    {
        private string email = ""; 
        public string Email { get => email; set => email = value ?? ""; }
    }
}
```

### And this is the code of my UI.

(It will send POST request to the API)

```
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace Practice_UI
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        async Task<bool> SendEmailToApi(string email)    
        {
            try
            {

                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())    
                {
                                                               
                    var json = new
                    {
                        email
                    };


                    string jsonEmail = JsonSerializer.Serialize(json);  

                    var content = new StringContent(jsonEmail, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    string apiUrl = "https://192.168.100.60:7214/api/Email"; 

                    
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(apiUrl, content);

                    
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        
                        string statusCode = response.StatusCode.ToString();
                        MessageBox.Show($"API請求失敗，狀態碼：{statusCode}", "API Request Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        return false;

                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"錯誤：{ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return false;
            }
        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string email = txtEmail.Text;

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email))
            {
                bool success = await SendEmailToApi(email);
                if (success)
                {
                    lblStatus.Text = "Email sent successfully!";
                    lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                }
                else
                {
                    lblStatus.Text = "Failed to send email.";
                    lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lblStatus.Text = "Please enter a valid email.";
                lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for reading my question, I will really be grateful if my question can be answered!!

Comment: [The markup](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Middleware/CORS/src/Infrastructure/CorsPolicyBuilder.cs#L37) says: `The origins that are allowed`. This means that the website sending the ajax-call to your api should run on the urls/origins you specify in your `WithOrigins` statement (which you just removed apparently)

Comment: The CorsMiddleware essentially checks if the `HttpContext.Request.Origin` is present in the list of allowed origins, and adds a response header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {the same origin from the request}`

Comment: `policy.WithOrigins.AllowAnyHeader()` - does not compile. Can you please share real code? Also please show the domains used in both cases. Also do you have some kind of reverse proxy set up?

Comment: @Pieterjan Sorry I'm new to this, where can I know the urls/origins? Or can I just allow any origin to send the call to API?
Cuz there will be many people from different domains visiting the API in the future.

Comment: The UI that you made (not in browser) should not care about CORS. CORS is a contract that browsers implement to be nicer to APIs on other origins. The API won't enforce it. I'm thinking there is something else going wrong.

Comment: You removed the `WithOrigins` call from the snippet. That's where the allowed origins are specified. The other website that's sending the ajax should be in there.

Comment: @juunas But the UI in the different computer will send POST request to the API, in this case, should UI not care about CORS?

Comment: @Pieterjan I add the `WithOrigins `back: `policy.WithOrigins("https://192.168.100.60:7214/api/Email")`
`192.168.100.60`is the IP where UI take place. Is it correct?

Comment: @Guru Stron I have corrected my code and add the code of API and UI. And I dont have reverse proxy ><

Comment: _"should UI not care about CORS?"_ - CORS is Cross-Origin Resource Sharing, it applies to requests send via scripting from browser from one site (origin) to another server. You are sending request directly via http client (i.e. you can consider it the same origin request).  Check the actual exception and add it to the question. Also are you sure that  7214 port on your machine is open to external requests?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if I get your question right, but to fully allow cross origin resource sharing, try

```
 options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                  policy =>
                  {
                      policy.AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .AllowAnyOrigin();
                  });
```

if that does not work, im am very convinced that you do not have a CORS, but a different network problem

also, your UI should not even care about CORS.

Comment: I tried this, and it still can't work ><

Comment: `AllowAnyOrigin` - do not ever do it unless for some quick-n-dirty dev/test scenarios or you want your app to be insecure. Also it will not work with credentials (`AllowCredentials`).

Comment: completely agree on that allowanyOrigins should only be done to test it.
@陳芸萱 if that does not work, are you sure you are having a cors issue, and not a different issue?   a cors error normally shows in the browser by bringing up an error like "preflight check fail..."... postman for example would not care about CORS